# MySQL index sort order

Tags: mysql

I have an `Invoice` table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Invoice (
    id           INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    countryCode  CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    number       INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

    ...

    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    UNIQUE KEY(countryCode ASC, number ASC)
);
```

Each country must have its own sequential invoice numbering, so before creating a new invoice, I have to get the next sequence number for this particular country using the following query:

```
SELECT MAX(number) + 1
FROM Invoice
WHERE countryCode = 'XX';
```

I understand that this query will use the index.

**Is there any incidence of the index sort order** (`number ASC` or `number DESC`) **on the performance of this query?**

Comment: Is someone doing VAT invoicing? :)

Comment: I have a whole service dedicated to just generating VAT invoice numbers :)

Comment: Is this something that you aren't capable of testing?

Comment: @Fresh It isn't, I'm just curious about theory. Or is it laziness?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP can test it themselves.

Comment: Yes I am happy with the column indexing, just wondering if because `MAX()` is asking for either the first or last row in the index, `ASC` or `DESC` would theoretically make any difference here.

Comment: @Benjamin I imagine that if MySQL supported DESC index that it still wouldn't matter. It would just know to look at first index entry for MAX() operation.

Comment: @Fresh, no hate please! Of course I can test it, but I'm interested to **understand** what's happing under the hood of the index, not just get two numbers and take a decision...

Comment: @Benjamin Then your question is off-topic and better suited for [dba.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have pretty much optimal index utilization since countryCode is first part of your key and the column you are getting max value for is second part of key. No need for sort here at all.  Check out this exceprt from MySQL documentation on index utilization

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html

> To find the MIN() or MAX() value for a specific indexed column
>   key_col. This is optimized by a preprocessor that checks whether you
>   are using WHERE key_part_N = constant on all key parts that occur
>   before key_col in the index. In this case, MySQL does a single key
>   lookup for each MIN() or MAX() expression and replaces it with a
>   constant. If all expressions are replaced with constants, the query
>   returns at once. For example:

```
SELECT MIN(key_part2),MAX(key_part2)   FROM tbl_name WHERE
key_part1=10;
```

Answer (score 1):

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

> An index_col_name specification can end with ASC or DESC. These keywords are permitted for future extensions for specifying ascending or descending index value storage. Currently, they are parsed but ignored; index values are always stored in ascending order.

I believe that with your statement, a key will only be created on `countryCode` and not `number`.

Comment: Oh, good to know. And in theory, if it *did* support them, would it make any difference according to you?

Comment: Although to answer your edit, no, a composite key is [definitely using all fields](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html).

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting the "ignored" bit. It is not the column with an explicit ASC or DESC that is ignored but the ASC/DESC specifier itself. MySQL still includes that column into the index and stores the values for it in the ascending order. (And in the OP's example both columns are ASC, so why would only one of them be included and not both I just can't fathom.)

Answer (score 1):

There will be small performance difference for `Select`statements, but bigger difference for `Insert`, `Update` and `Delete` statements.

When you insert in the middle of a full page, then DB engine should move some rows to next page. If you have `DESC` then every `INSERT` should move index rows over pages. Same for `DELETE` ones.

`Updates`are not so affected, but if you change index values same thing applies.